# How do I change what my Assistant Editor view is in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have the MessageCell.xib open on the left. However, when I try to open the Assistant Editor for MessageCell.swift, I cannot seem to do so. Below is a screenshot of my project. The red box is what I want to be the MessageCell.swift file. Any suggestions?

This is a view of my Xcode project:

[image: This is a view of my Xcode project]

I have tried cycling through where it says "counterparts" in the top left of the red box of the screenshot, but no such luck. I'm a new Xcode student and trying to learn everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the assistant editor, you can open MessageCell.swift in a new editor by finding the file in the project navigator, holding Option+Shift, then clicking on the file. Press the right arrow key to indicate a new editor and press enter. If you want to do the whole process with keyboard rather than project navigator, press Cmd+Shift+O, type the file name, hold Option+Shift, then press enter.

Comment: You are a genius, Dalton! This worked. I'll have to remember this trick. I sincerely appreciate your prompt help!

Comment: @mdn0403 Happy to help. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.